# Dynamic Routing in next Js result 404 not found in the production Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Dynamic Routing in next JS. Everything works Fine in the development mode. If I access dynamic page first it will load the page. But if I refresh the page I am getting the 404 not found error.

Comment: Try to add code snippit for better understanding of the question

Comment: `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post`

Answer (score 1):

the issue ur encountering is likely because of client-side routing in Next.js which only works when navigation between pages dynamically and dose not handle page refreshes or direct url access